# How to get a row number from entry in results - SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

In SQLite how do I get the row number of a specific result?

Consider my data is the following

```
Username          UserLevel
 James            23
 Tim              24
 John             22
```

What I'd like to return is the position in the statement where said person is. IE

```
Select * from users where Username='John' (+ SOME LOGIC);
```

Returns

```
3
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is there some reason you want the row number rather than retrieving the entry's primary key?

Comment: @Powerlord - To return the "Rank" of the user - Essentially a highscores type of ordeal

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering to the rows unless an explicit `order by` is used.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ROW_NUMBER(). ROW_NUMBER is a temporary value calculated when the query is run

Comment: How so? Select row number ?

Comment: it must be in sub query. For example in your case; select * from (

select Username,
      UserLevel,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Username) AS RowNumber
) as x

where x.Username = 'John'

Comment: There are two users 'John' in the sample data. So why would it return 3? Why not 1?

Comment: @DinoCoderSaurus - Good Catch. Meant to be only 1

Comment: you can then extend your where clause with UserLevel

Comment: @DotSlashShell sqlite has had window functions since 3.25.